# Filter my markers based on description (a column) from my database using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, leaflet

I am trying to filter my markers based on description (a column) from my oracle database. I have created a query (filter.py) which has been sent to ajax as json to allow users to select on one or more type of description (e.g Rock, Knoll, etc) with the submission button allowing the filter to be possible. The query has been sent to ajax but I don't know how to go about it in jquery, so that if a user checks a box based on rock description, he will on get markers that are described as rocks and he can also get markers describe as knoll etc. I am using leaflet js library.. I am really new to jquery

```
     <div class="btn-group">
        <input type="button"class="btn btn-default"  id="allmarkers">Submit</input>
       <input type="checkbox" id="Rock">Rock</input>
       <input type='checkbox' id= "Knoll">Knoll</input>
      </div>

var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

 L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a 
 href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

  //generate marker cluster
 // var myRenderer = L.canvas({ padding: 5 });
 var markers= L.markerClusterGroup({
 });


 {% for item in markers %}

   //create map icons from database (this calls marker from a python query created using jnja2 template)

 var marker{{ item[0] }} = L.marker({{ item[3:] }})

 markers.addLayer(marker{{ item[0] }});
 map.addLayer(markers)

{% endfor %} 




 Queries to filter(filter.py) (sent to ajax)

 #!/usr/bin/env python3

 import cgi 
 import cgitb 
 import sys 
 import json
 import cx_Oracle 
 cgitb.enable()

 from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
 fs = cgi.FieldStorage()



desc=[]
if 'description' in fs:
    desc=fs['description'].value



def getMarkers():
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect(dsn="geosgen", user="s4346", password=pw)
    c = conn.cursor()
    query = "SELECT A.PLACENAME_ID, A.DESCRIPTION, A.LATITUDE, A.LONGITUDE FROM PLACENAMES A"

    if len(desc)>0:
        query = query +getDescriptionQuery()
c.execute(query)
    markers = []
    for row in c:
    markers.append([row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3]])
    conn.close
    return markers

 def getDescriptionQuery():
     query=''
     for index, element in enumerate(desc):
        if index==0:
            query=query + "WHERE A.DESCRIPTION = '"+ desc[index] +"' "
    else:
            query=query + "OR A.DESCRIPTION = '"+ desc[index] +"' "
    return query

 markers=getMarkers()


 result= {'data': markers}


   sys.stdout.write("Content-Type: application/json")
  sys.stdout.write("\n")
  sys.stdout.write("\n")
  sys.stdout.write(json.dumps(result,indent=1))
  sys.stdout.write("\n")

  sys.stdout.close()





    AJAX CALL

    $("#allmarkers").click(function (evt) {
   $.ajax({
 url: "/~s1774346/cgi-bin/filter.py",
 async: true,
 type: "post",
 datatype:"json",
 data: {'description': ['Rock', 'Knoll'] },
  //data: "",

 success: function(response) {
     var dataArr = response.data
        console.log(response.data)



//NOT SURE ABOUT HOW TO DO THE FILTERIING FROM HERE

$("#Rock").on('change', function(event){
  if (this.checked){
     for (var i = 0; i < dataArr.length; i++) {
      console.log(dataArr[0])
                if (description[0]== "Rock"){

}else { 

} 
    }
     }

 });



}
        });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do that would be to filter them when you get them from ajax:

```
var rock_group_markers = knoll_group_markers = new L.featureGroup();

$.ajax({
    url: "/~s1774346/cgi-bin/filter.py",
    async: true,
    type: "post",
    datatype: "json",
    data: {'description': ['Rock', 'Knoll']},   
    success: function (response) {
        var dataArr = response.data
        // For each result from your request
        dataArr.forEach(function(item) {
            // Create popup if you need it
            var popup = 'Your popup data' + item.description + item.title;
            if (item.description === 'Rock') {
                // Create marker
                // if item.latlng doesn't exist you have to create it like this
                // var latlng = new L.latLng(-43.1731, 6.6906);
                L.marker(item.latlng, {icon: youIcon}).bindPopup(popup).addTo(rock_group_markers);
            } else if (item.description === 'Knoll') {
                L.marker(item.latlng, {icon: youIcon}).bindPopup(popup).addTo(knoll_group_markers);
            }
        })
    }
});

$('#Rock').change(function() {
    if($("#Rock").prop('checked') === true){
        // Is checked add to map
        map.addLayer(rock_group_markers);
    } else {
        // Remove from map
        map.removeLayer(rock_group_markers);
    }
});
```

I'm using a `featureGroup` so you can store all your Rock markers inside it. It's then really easy to add or remove this layer from the map.